# Wordpress putting "rn" in every line break?

Tags: plugins, html

I am using a Wordpress plugin called "WP Checkout" and there is a custom post field that allows you to enter additional product information which is tabulated on the product page.

I am able to enter HTML into these tabs, but for some reason, the HTML becomes malformed when I save the changes and "rn" is added in every line break. This issue didn't used to exist, it seems like it only started happening since I updated to the latest Wordpress version.

The issue can be seen here: http://xactsensing.com/transmisor-del-flujo-de-lodo/#tabs13-2

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Original post updated, I realized the issue was not due to the multilingual plugin but to the latest Wordpress update.

Comment: Can you post the code that displays those blocks of content?

Comment: I contacted the plugin developer and they informed me that this issue is caused by the TinyMCE editor they are using in the plugin, they have disabled it for now and sent me a new version which is working correctly. Thanks!